# Why tree iteration is not properly working in python class

Tags: python, class

This question occurred to me when I was doing 173. Binary Search Tree Iterator on leetcode:

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BSTIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
    """
    :type root: TreeNode
    """
        self.root = root

    def next(self):
    """
    :rtype: int
    """
        self.point = self.root
        while self.point.left:
            self.point = self.point.left
        #self.point = self.point.left
        #self.point.val = 1000
        self.point = None
```

And then when I ran:

```
root = TreeNode(0)
root.left = TreeNode(1)
root.right = TreeNode(2)
iterat.next()
iterat.root.left.val
```

I was expecting None, but it returned 1 anyway. Is there any explanation?

Comment: How do you initialize your `iterat`, it is not shown here.

Comment: iterat = BSTIterator(root). And after initializing, I ran iterat.next() for two times, expecting to get None. But I always got 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get None is because you did not change `self.root` at all. Instead, you create `self.point` in your next function, mutate the `self.point` only.

You can add one line at bottom.

```
print(iterat.point)
```

and it will return you,

```
None
```